# Intersection of words in a list ( just the words appearing in all elements, not sorted order)

Tags: python-2.7

I need to extract words common to all the elements in a list created by a list.append iteration. I do not wish to split -to-words-->sort-->count because if the word pattern is a n-gram , then I will have equal counts for each word in the n-gram.
For example, in a list of known length two:

```
set(xy[0].split(' ')).intersection(set(xy[1].split(' ')))
```

If I have to iterate over an arbitrary length, I get an error. I have `set.intersection(set(ci) for ci in xy)` which returns a TypeError: descriptor 'intersection' requires a 'set' object but received a 'generator'. Mentally, the problem statement is how do I find the intersecting words **across** all elements in an iteration? Many thanks. And sorry, I still think in FORTRAN.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can [unpack](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#unpacking-argument-lists) with *:

```
xy = [[1,2,3],[2,3]]
print(set.intersection(*(set(ci) for ci in xy)))
{2, 3}
```

Or use map:

```
xy = [[1,2,3],[2,3]]
print(set.intersection(*map(set,xy)))
{2, 3}
```

If you want to maintain the order, you can find the intersection of the lists and use an OrderedDict to get the unique values:

```
strs = ["prime minister David Cameroon,", "PM David Cameroon,", "David Cameroon, British prime minister"]

from collections import OrderedDict
inter = set.intersection(*map(set, map(str.split, strs)))

print(list(OrderedDict.fromkeys(v for v in strs[0].split() if v in inter).keys()))

['David', 'Cameroon,']
```

We just need to just iterate over the first split substring from the list as for any word to appear in inter it must be in all three.

You could use a list comp but if David or Cameroon appeared more than once in the first string you would end up with dupes in the output list, the OrderedDict makes sure you keep the order seen and only add each substring once. You might also want to consider sripping punctuation from words and calling lower if you consider `cameroon,` and `Cameroon` to be the same.

Comment: Brilliant. What does the star do?

Comment: @Pradeep. it unpacks the list, I was looking for the link to the docs, I added it above

Comment: Thanks. How do I retain the order of the words? "prime minister Cameroon," "PM Cameroon," and "David Cameroon, British prime minister" and some such returns ['Cameroon', 'David']. How do I get the right order?

Comment: Sets are unordered. If you want order we need a different approach